# Series Mismatch (Find value in "mismatched" Series)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, find

Feel like I should know this. I am attempting to compare two DataFrames and find those individuals who are not included:

## First df

```
data_x = {'Num':[321654,654987, 654321], 'Name':['Tim', 'Jake', 'Sam']}
x = pd.DataFrame(data_x)
```

### x =

```
0    321654    Tim
1    654987    Jake
2    654321    Sam
```

## Second df

```
data_z = {'Num':[321654,123456, 654987,894523], 'Name':['Tim', 'Jim', 'Jake', 'Bob']}
z = pd.DataFrame(data_z)
```

### z =

```
0    321654    Tim
1    123456    Jim
2    654987    Jake
3    894523    Bob
```

## Requested Results =

```
0    123456    Jim
1    894523    Bob
```

Comment: Is the `Jakez` in second df actually `Jake` ?

Comment: lol, yeah c/p error. Fixed

Comment: Any further clarification needed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a outer [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `x` and `z` with parameter `indicator=True` and check for those merge result with `right_only`, as follows:

```
out = x.merge(z, how='outer', indicator=True)

# You can also specify the 2 columns if there are other columns in real situation
# out = x.merge(z, on=['Num', 'Name']  how='outer', indicator=True)
```

Result:

```
print(out)

      Num  Name      _merge
0  321654   Tim        both
1  654987  Jake        both
2  654321   Sam   left_only
3  123456   Jim  right_only
4  894523   Bob  right_only
```

and then filter the result by:

```
out.loc[out['_merge'] == 'right_only']
```

Output:

```
      Num Name      _merge
3  123456  Jim  right_only
4  894523  Bob  right_only
```

Of course you can remove the merge result column and reset the index, if you like:

```
out_filtered = out.loc[out['_merge'] == 'right_only']
out_filtered = out_filtered.drop(columns='_merge').reset_index(drop=True)


print(out_filtered)


      Num Name
0  123456  Jim
1  894523  Bob
```